Use ThisRecord in LookUp function
i am trying to filter the items in a gallery based on the answers in another item. My source for the gallery looks like this.
Once the user selects an option in the gallery through a radio control, the selected Option is written to the OptionSelected column.



Title
OptionSelected
Visible




1.1.1

always


1.1.2

1.1.1,Option 1


1.1.3

1.1.1,Option 2



I want the items only to be visible, if the criteria in column Visible is met.
This is my code for the gallery Items which works just like it should.
Filter(colQuestions,
    Visible = "always" ||
    Visible = 
    Concatenate(
        First(Split(ThisRecord.Visible,",")).Value,
        ",",
        LookUp(colQuestions, Title =  "1.1.1").OptionSelected
    )
    
 )

What i am trying to do now is to replace the "1.1.1" in the LookUp function, so that it gets the information from the column visible. With the Split function used above. Like that.
Filter(colQuestions,Menu=gblNumMenu,Submenu=gblNumSubmenu, Commission=gblTextCommission,
    Visible = "always" ||
    Visible = 
    Concatenate(
        First(Split(ThisRecord.Visible,",")).Value,
        ",",
        LookUp(colQuestions, Title =  First(Split(ThisRecord.Visible,",")).Value).OptionSelected
    )
    
 )

With this block, the items are all filtered out.
I also tried to separate the two informations "1.1.1" and "Option 1" / "Option 2" in separate columns, but that did not work either.
Is there a possibility, to combine ThisRecord with LookUp, the way I am trying to?
Thanks for your help!

I think i found something myself. It seems to work in combination with the As function. Maybe that helps someone else.
Does this make sense, or is there a better solution?
Filter(
        colQuestions As locColQuestions,

        locColQuestions.Visible = "always" ||
        locColQuestions.Visible = 
        Concatenate(
            First(Split(locColQuestions.Visible,",")).Value,
            ",",
            LookUp(colQuestions, Title =  First(Split(locColQuestions.Visible,",")).Value).OptionSelected
        )        
    )

